# How to test new version of windows service without uninstalling old service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

Does anyone know how to install a duplicate of a Windows service? I need to test a new version of a service that I have written, but would like to do so without uninstalling the old version of the service. If there are any problems with the new service, I will need to restart the old service as quickly as possible. I attempted re-naming the new service everywhere that I could find to rename it (from project name to assembly.cs), but it still recognized the old install and would not allow me to install a new version without uninstalling the old version.

If this is not possible, I can always just keep the old .msi handy and be prepared to re-install. It would just be convenient to be able to have them both installed and switch between them if there are any issues.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Separate machine? Separate VM??

Comment: Has to be on the same machine. BTW, already tried this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/MultipleInstNetWinService.aspx. It doesn't work in vs2008.

Answer (score 2):

You should install the service from different folders and register it with different name in SCM.

the consuming applications should have a setting in config or web.config or wherever where you can set the name of the testing or productive service.

Comment: Could you provide more details? From what I know, the default install location is autogenerated based on AssemblyInfo.cs and then may be modified during the installation process. However, I get an error on launching the .msi that says "Another version of this product is already installed". Also, I'm not familiar with SCM or reading the config on install.

Comment: somewhere in the properties of the .msi project there should be the service name, i never installed services with an msi, used the installUtil command from a batch file from where you could specify service name and description :)

Comment: I can change service name and description all I want. It still recognizes that there is an older version installed.